# updating variable in angular Service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I am new to angular and trying to update variable but I variable is not updating in view. I am accessing a variable "name" created in service and updating it but it isn't working. When I call `clickme()` the value of variable name doesn't update on the webpage and shows old value "no name". I want to change the variable name value to "rahul" and display it on the page.

my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirstService {
  name:string="no name"

  setName() {
    this.name="rahul"
  }
}
```

code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstServiceService } from './first-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [FirstService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  account:any
  name:string
  constructor(private userName:FirstService){      }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name=this.userName.name
  }
  clickMe(e){
    this.userName.setName()
  }
}
```

Comment: create 2 method getName and setName of service file and than first set the name and than get the name.
*tip:* use service name in the component as same as service name but in camel case `private firstService: FirstService)`

Comment: you forget that when calling a function if you want to return a value dont forget the keyword "return", on your service you call a function but not returning a value.

  setName() {
    this.name="rahul"
return this.name;
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually do with this way:

**Service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FirstService {
    private name:string="no name";

    setName(_name: string): void {
        this.name = _name;
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirstService } from './first-service.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [FirstService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  account:any
  name:string
  constructor(private firstService: FirstService){      }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.name=this.firstService.getName();
  }
  clickMe(e){
    this.userName.setName("rahul");
    this.name=this.firstService.getName();
  }
}
```

Whereas I must admit that the value of name normally doesn't get set by the same method that afterwards consumes it from the service. At least not when these are the only 2 lines of code in the method, though. But I reckon you're still playing around a little with services and then it's okay.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it solved your problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the same variable name in service like component.You can use anything you want.

In App component

```
clickMe(e){
    this.name=this.userName.setName();
}
```

In service

```
getName() {
    return this.name;
}
```

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You only equals the variable "name" to this.userName.name in OnInit, this is the reason because you don't see any change -you're showing the variable "name", not the variable this.usuerName.Name.

Normally you can use some simple, it's a getter
You can write in component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  account:any
  //NOT have a variable "name", just a getter
  get name(){
      return this.userName.name;
  }
  //even if you want you can write
  set name(value)
  { 
      this.userName.name=value;
  }
  constructor(private userName:FirstService){      }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  clickMe(e){
    this.userName.setName()
    //or this.name="George"; //if you include the function set name()
    //or this.userName.name="George"
  }
}
```